# char[] return type in code not accepting char[i][] value

Tags: java

```
public char[] Cache_1(int word_address,int cache_set,int ls,char[] s1)
{
    char cache_1[][] = new char[32][4];

    char s0[] = new char[32];
    InterConnectionNetwork ic =  new InterConnectionNetwork();

    if(ls == '0') {
        if((cache_1[cache_set][0]) == '1') { // Check Valid Bit and transfer content 
                                             // if valid bit is high
            for(int i=0;i<32;i++) {          // Load
               s0[i] = cache_1[cache_set][i];
            }
        } else {                             // Valid bit low
          s0 = ic.determinenode(word_address);                    
        }            
        return s0;
    } else {        
        if((cache_1[cache_set][0]) == '1') {
            for(int i=0;i<32;i++) {
                cache_1[cache_set][i] = s0[i];
            }
        } else
            cache_1[cache_set][] = ic.determinenode(word_address);  //returns char[]    
        return (cache_1[cache_set][]);       //Problem here
    }          
}
```

This is a chunk from the code that I am writing. The problem here is that return type being used is `char[]` and `cache_1[cache_set][]` is actually equivalent to single character array, but it is showing an error. Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return `cache_1[cache_set]`, not `cache_1[cache_set][]`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined return type as

```
 char[]
```

which means char array (linear)

and you are returning

```
cache_1[cache_set][] //should give multiple error and one for not giving index inside the second [?]
```

if you write this correctly then you are returning an `char` not `char[]`
You have to change any one of it.